# What would be the mathematical equivalent of the CUMPRINC formula in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Working on an application where I want to calculate the principal paid down on a mortgage after n years.

Mortgage (M) of $100,000
Interest (I) of 5%
Amortization Term (T) of 25 years
Monthly Pmt (P) is $581.60 (Canadian Mortgage)
Scenario: 5 years or 60 mths

The CUMPRINC formula is:

CUMPRINC((I/2+1)^(2/12)-1, (T * 12), M, 1, 60, 0) = $11,492.49

Tried to find the formula but all the sources found so far don't break down an example that I've been able to make work.

Thanks!

Comment: Dp you want to program it yourself? Or do you just need to understand the function inputs in order to use it correctly? If the former, I suggest you look for a free amortisation calculator template in Excel. It would be easier to calculate the principal paid down manually using a row by row/payment after payment table, where the remaining total interest and principal amounts reflect at the end of each month. You might also be able to derive formula yourself by studying amortisation from sources such as wikipedia.

Comment: I'm looking for the math equivalent of the Excel function for an application that I'm developing. It's very straight forward in Excel or Google Sheets but I'm looking for pure math solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found an excellent answer on the post
[How do I calculate the principal paid down on a mortgage?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/71370/how-do-i-calculate-the-principal-paid-down-on-a-mortgage/73683#73683)

I quote this answer below:

> The question is: "I'd like to know how much I'd have in principal paid
> off against the mortgage after n periods."
>
> It is slightly unclear whether you want the principal repaid or the
> principal remaining so here are formulas for the principal remaining
> in month n, the principal repaid in month n, and the accumulated
> principal repaid in month n.
>
> ```
> p[n] = (d + (1 + r)^n (r s - d))/r
>
> pr[n] = (d - r s) (r + 1)^(n - 1)
>
> accpr[n] = (d - r s) ((1 + r)^n - 1)/r
> ```
>
> where
>
> ```
> p[n] is the principal remaining in month n, i.e the balance
> pr[n] is the principal repayment in month n
> accpr[n] is the accumulated principal repaid in month n
>
> s is the initial loan principal
> r is the monthly interest rate i.e. nominal annual rate ÷ 12
> d is the regular monthly payment
> ```
>
> **Example**
>
> Taking a £1000 loan over 3 years with 10% interest per month (rather
> high, but it's just an example), the monthly repayment `d` by
> [standard
> formula](http://www.financeformulas.net/Loan_Payment_Formula.html) is
>
> ```
> s = 1000
> r = 0.1
> n = 36
>
> d = r s/(1 - (1 + r)^-n) = 103.34306381837332
> ```
>
> Using these figures in a calculation of the principal remaining, i.e.
> the balance:
>
> ```
> s = 1000
> r = 0.1
> d = 103.34306381837332
>
> n = 36
> p[n] = (d + (1 + r)^n (r s - d))/r = 0 as expected
> ```
>
> ***Plot of principal remaining over the 3 year term***
>
> `p[n] = (d + (1 + r)^n (r s - d))/r` for `n = 0` to `n = 36`
>
> [image]
>
> Likewise for the calculation of the principal repayments:
>
> ***Plot of principal repayments over the 3 year term***
>
> `pr[n] = (d - r s) (r + 1)^(n - 1)` for `n = 1` to `n = 36`
>
> [image]
>
> The accumulated principal repayments after 36 months:
>
> ```
> n = 36
> accpr[36] = (d - r s) ((1 + r)^n - 1)/r = 1000
> ```
>
> compared with total repayments of `36 d = 3720.35`.
>
> *Example amortisation table*
>
> ```
> month  interest   principal repayment =          accumulated     balance
> n      at 10%     payment - interest repayment   princ. repmt.   p[n]
> 0                                                                1000
> 1      100        103.34306 - 100 = 3.34306        3.34306       996.657
> 2      99.6657    103.34306 - 99.6657 = 3.67737    7.02043       992.98
> 3      99.2979    103.34306 - 99.2979 = 4.04511    11.0655       988.934
> ...
> 35     17.9356    103.34306 - 17.9356 = 85.4075    906.052       93.9482
> 36     9.39482    103.34306 - 9.39482 = 93.9482    1000          0
> ```
>
> **Derivation**
>
> The balance of a loan follows this recurrence equation.
>
> ```
> p[n + 1] = p[n] (1 + r) - d
> ```
>
> where
>
> ```
> p[n] is the balance of the loan in month n
> r is the monthly interest rate
> d is the regular monthly payment
> ```
>
> This can be solved like so (using *Mathematica* in this instance).
>
> ```
> RSolve[{p[n + 1] == p[n] (1 + r) - d, p[0] == s}, p[n], n]
> ```
>
> where `s is the initial loan principal`
>
> yielding `p[n_] := (d + (1 + r)^n (r s - d))/r`
>
> This notation expresses a formula for the balance in month n, which
> can be used in a function for the principal repayment `pr`, (that is,
> the regular repayment less the payment of interest on the previous
> month's balance).
>
> ```
> pr[n_] := d - (p[n - 1] r)
> ```
>
> Combining these expressions produces an expression in terms of d, r, s
> & n.
>
> ```
> pr[n_] := (d - r s) (r + 1)^(n - 1)
> ```
>
> After `n` periods the accumulated principal repaid is:
>
> `accpr[n] = Σ(d - r s) (r + 1)^(k - 1)` for `k = 1` to `k = n`
>
> ∴ by induction, `accpr[n] = (d - r s) ((1 + r)^n - 1)/r`
>
> **Addendum**
>
> The above results can be obtained more simply using the [standard
> formula for the present value of an ordinary
> annuity](http://www.financeformulas.net/Present_Value_of_Annuity.html),
> treating the remaining portion of the mortgage as a small loan itself.
>
> For example, obtaining values for month 28.
>
> ```
> s = 1000
> r = 0.1
> n = 36
>
> P = r s/(1 - (1 + r)^-n) = 103.34306381837332
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> The balance remaining in month 28
>
> ```
> x = 36 - 28 = 8
>
> balance = P(1 - (1 + r)^-x)/r = 551.328
>
> principal paid = principal - balance = 448.672
> ```
>
> Which agrees with the previous formulation
>
> ```
> accpr[28] = 448.672
> ```
>
> and as Wick provides for Excel and Google Sheets
>
> ```
> =CUMPRINC(0.1,36,1000,1,28,0)
> ```
>
> > ```
> > -448.672
> > ```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good and I should be what I need. It's the accumulated principal paid after n months that I was looking for.